# Firebase Storage Error: 404 - ACCESS_BUCKET

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Im trying to upload an image to Firebase storage. When i try to upload the image, i get the error as 404, but i have created the storage in firebase.

Firebase npm version :  `firebase": "^7.24.0`

Error:

```
code: 404
message: "Not Found.  Could not access bucket \"<project>.appspot.com\""
status: "ACCESS_BUCKET"
```

Storage Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase Initialization:

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
});

export const analytics = app.analytics();
export const storage = firebase.storage();
export default app;
```

Service JS :

```
export async function uploadImageCloud(image){
    const storageRef = storage.ref("image/" + image.name);
    return storageRef.put(image);
}
```

Upload function:

```
function uploadImage(){
        setDataImageUploading(true);
        uploadImageCloud(getDataImage).then((data)=>{
            console.log(data);
            setDataImageUploading(false);
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e);
            setDataImageUploading(false);
        });
    }
```

Any idea where did i messed up?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally I found out that the value of the `storageBucket` passed to `initializeApp` is very sensitive data. It should be **exactly** the bucket name on the top files(without gs://):

[image]

in this project for example it is `steem-engine-dex.appspot.com`.

```js
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  //...
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  //...
});
```

**Important:**

- storageBucket is **case sensitive**. e.g. steem-engine-dex.app**S**pot.com is invalid
- storageBucket shouldn't include any extra space in beginning or end. e.g. `steem-engine-dex.appspot.com`  and  `steem-engine-dex.appspot.com` are invalid

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked for me. The mistake from my side was i had given the env variable quotes i.e. `"<project>.appspot.com"` instead it should have been just `<project>.appspot.com`. Also take care the string must not have any white spaces as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @SushanSapaliga, glad to hear that your issue is fixed.