# Can't access to an uploaded image in Cloud Storage for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

I uploaded an image to Cloud Storage for Firebase following this: [upload images tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress) and I got a URL in this format:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxx/o/UploadedImages%2FvAVBs5PTWkXdV7FnfnCO6bEuG4E3%2F1661780880042.png?alt=media&token=yyyyy
```

Then I set the URL in an Image and this return `404`

[image]

The uploaded image is saved with this name, firestore is adding a suffix `_430x1300`:

[image: image uploaded]

Some rarely times it works correctly and I can see the image, but in the most of the cases I cant see the image

### Edit:

Also I can see the image preview in `console.firebase.google.com`

Also I found a difference between the Url in `console.firebase.google.com` as...

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxx/o/UploadedImages%2FvAVBs5PTWkXdV7FnfnCO6bEuG4E3%2F1661780880042_430x1300.png?alt=media&token=yyyyy
```

and Url generate by `getDownloadURL` as...

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxx/o/UploadedImages%2FvAVBs5PTWkXdV7FnfnCO6bEuG4E3%2F1661786226469.jpeg?alt=media&token=yyyyy
```

`getDownloadURL` is returning a different and invalid URL

### Update: this is the code

```js
if (!user) return;
console.log("[UPLOAD NODE IMAGES]");
const storage = getStorage();
if (!isUploading && !choosingNode) {
  try {
    event.preventDefault();
    const image = event.target.files[0];
    if (
      image.type !== "image/jpg" &&
      image.type !== "image/jpeg" &&
      image.type !== "image/gif" &&
      image.type !== "image/png"
      ) {
        alert("We only accept JPG, JPEG, PNG, or GIF images. Please upload another image.");
    } else {
      setIsSubmitting(true);
      setIsUploading(true);
      const picturesFolder = "UploadedImages/";
      const imageNameSplit = image.name.split(".");
      const imageExtension = imageNameSplit[imageNameSplit.length - 1];
      let imageFileName = user.userId + "/" + new Date().toUTCString() + "." + imageExtension;

      const storageRef = ref(storage, picturesFolder + imageFileName);

      const task = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);
      task.on(
        "state_changed",
        function progress(snapshot: any) {
          setPercentageUploaded(Math.ceil((100 * snapshot.bytesTransferred) / snapshot.totalBytes));
        },
        function error(err: any) {
          setIsSubmitting(false);
          setIsUploading(false);
          alert(
              "There is an error with uploading your image. Please upload it again! If the problem persists, please try another image."
          );
        },
        async function complete() {
          console.log("storageRef", storageRef);
          const imageGeneratedUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

          setIsSubmitting(false);
          setIsUploading(false);
          if (imageGeneratedUrl && imageGeneratedUrl !== "") {
            setNodeParts(nodeId, (thisNode: any) => {
              thisNode.nodeImage = imageGeneratedUrl;
              return { ...thisNode };
            });
          }
          setPercentageUploaded(100);
        }
      );
    }
  } catch (err) {
      console.error("Image Upload Error: ", err);
      setIsUploading(false);
      setIsSubmitting(false);
  }
}
```

#### Postscript

- Im working with "firebase": "^9.9.0"
- Im working in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- I removed all extensions from browser
- I update all packages in my SO

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344001/firebase-storage-error-404-access-bucket or look up 'firebase storage 404'. 
Looks like an issue with the access config or permissions issue. Check if there are any more logs or error messages to help troubleshoot the error and try seeing if you can access the stored image in an incognito tab to see if it's publicly accessible

Comment: No, is not because I can see the Images uploaded in `console.firebase.google.com`

Comment: And you can see the image in the browser with the url + access token?

Comment: I can't see in the browser, I get this in the browser: "error": {    "code": 404, message": "Not Found."   }

Comment: Are you sure your reference is correct? [This error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors#handle_error_messages) seems to be due to the fact that the object doesn’t exist at the desired reference. Please share how you created your Cloud Storage reference. To download the image directly in the browser, you must configure your Cloud Storage bucket for cross-origin access [(CORS)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration).

Comment: I dont think is the cors, sometimes it works and in the **most of the cases is not working**

I've just update adding the code